QtCharts. How to display the first label of QCategoryAxis when its position is QCategoryAxis::AxisLabelsPositionOnValue and it is the start of range
There is the simple code
BaseGraphWidget::BaseGraphWidget(QWidget *parent) : QChartView(parent) {
    auto xAxis = new QCategoryAxis(this);
    xAxis->setLabelsPosition(QCategoryAxis::AxisLabelsPositionOnValue);
    xAxis->append("0", 0);
    xAxis->append("1", 1);
    xAxis->append("4", 4);
    xAxis->setRange(0, 4);
    xAxis->setStartValue(0);

    QLineSeries *ser = new QLineSeries(this);
    *ser << QPointF(0, 0) << QPointF(1, 2) << QPointF(4, 7);

    chart()->addAxis(xAxis, Qt::AlignBottom);
    chart()->addSeries(ser);

The result is
Graph
So one question: where is 0?
I dont know what to try
